# Does wet dream ejaculation reduce Ojas?

Tags: brahmacharya, wet-dreams, ojas

I have ejaculated through a wet dream involuntarily. Is it a breakdown in the path of brahmacharya and do I lose a significant amount of ojas by this emission of semen? If so , how can I retain the lost Ojas ?

Comment: Wet Dreams do not break Brahmacharya vow

One's vow of Brahmacharya is not broken by having wet dreams. In such cases the expiation laid down consists in the pouring of libations of clarified butter on the blazing fire.

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section XXXIV-XXXV

Comment: I am sorry @Hope but I did not understand the last line of your answer. Could you please explain it. Thank you.

Comment: Bro last line means to do a havan with ghee, I have checked hindi translation and saying that